# filling an array of integers from TextBox

Tags: c#, arrays, string, winforms, collections

I have a textbox in my winforms application , when i taped this value for example **1258**

```
 int[] arr = new int[] { textBox1.Text[0], textBox1.Text[1], textBox1.Text[2], textBox1.Text[3] };
```

the content of `arr` is : 49,50,53,56 Not 1,2,5,8 !!!

Even I used [StringTrim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) method , I get the same result

I need to know what is the reason of this error?? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to implicit conversion from `char` to `int`.

You are getting the `ASCII` values of your chars. Try this instead:

```
var arr = textBox1.Text.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are getting the ASCII code instead of Integer value.

In ASCII the char '0' = 48 = 30h

Then you can get the integer value using this (for example):
textBox1.Text[0] - 48

Note that it gonna work only for values with 1 digit, for more digits you have to parse the text.

Answer (score -1):

It inserts the ASCII values to the array. So instead of a 0 it inserts a 48, instead of 1 it inserts a 49 and so on.

If you want the real number from a text you need to parse it with `int.Parse("1")`.
So for your array this should work, even if it's not the best solution.

```
int[] arr = new int[] { int.Parse(textBox1.Text[0]), int.Parse(textBox1.Text[1]), int.Parse(textBox1.Text[2]), int.Parse(textBox1.Text[3]) };
```